# how to merge two imodel into one (using IModelTransformer)

Tags: imodeljs

Please save me.
I'm trying to merge two imodel into one output bim file. 
Ex) source1 = test1.bim, source 2= test2.bim output = output.bim 
output.bim should have both test1 and test2 when I rendered when I open the output.bim file using Snapshot, meaning it should have both elements for test1 and test2.

I looked over https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/issues/87. However, it only says "Use IModelTransformer". 
I also looked over https://www.itwinjs.org/learning/backend/imodeltransformation/

https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/tree/master/test-apps/imodel-transformer

https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/blob/master/core/backend/src/test/standalone/IModelTransformer.test.ts

documentation, but no luck yet.

Can anyone give me an example code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the transformer tests there is an example showing some snapshot iModels loaded from disk and merged:
[https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/blob/master/core/backend/src/test/standalone/IModelTransformer.test.ts](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/blob/2f29248e9014a076f454f55079fd223ff8207369/core/backend/src/test/standalone/IModelTransformer.test.ts#L836)

The process is as follows:

1. It creates an empty "merge" iModel
2. inserts a subject for each model to be merged
3. open in sequence each model to merge, remap the root subject of this iModel to the inserted subject in the "merge" model, and run the transformer to export everything from the "model-to-merge" and import it into the "merge" iModel. Note the required `targetScopeElementId` here.

Briefly, it should look something like:

```js
const mergedDb = SnapshotDb.createEmpty("/tmp/merged.bim", { rootSubject: { name: "Merge Test" } });
// prepare some subjects to merge onto
const model1SubjectId = Subject.insert(mergedDb, IModel.rootSubjectId, "Model1Subject");
const model2SubjectId = Subject.insert(mergedDb, IModel.rootSubjectId, "Model2Subject");

// merge first source model
const sourceModel1 = SnapshotDb.openFile("/tmp/sourceModel1.bim");
const transformer1 = new IModelTransformer(sourceModel1, mergedDb, { targetScopeElementId: model1SubjectId });
transformer1.context.remapElement(IModel.rootSubjectId, source1SubjectId);
await transformer1.processAll(); // export everything from sourceModel1 and import into merged

// merge second source model
const sourceModel2 = SnapshotDb.openFile("/tmp/sourceModel2.bim");
const transformer2 = new IModelTransformer(sourceModel2, mergedDb, { targetScopeElementId: model2SubjectId });
transformer2.context.remapElement(IModel.rootSubjectId, source2SubjectId);
await transformer2.processAll(); // export everything from sourceModel2 and import into merged

sourceModel1.close();
sourceModel2.close();
mergedDb.saveChanges();
```

Also make sure to import any schemas with `processSchemas`, the linked test has an explicit example.

Comment: I have merged into one iModel thanks to you, when I put it in a viewer (snapshot) merged iModel bim file doesn't show both iModel objects in one viewer, rather it shows in two different viewer. How can I solve this? (both objects from source1 and source2 should be shown in one viewer combined)

Comment: in one view port

Comment: @HasungJun do you still have a problem with this? Sorry I missed this comment... Maybe you can start a github discussion to discuss further? https://github.com/iTwin/itwinjs-core/discussions